# Get page content from separate page into div on form submit without reloading current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, submit

I'm attempting to fetch data from another page and load its response and content into a div in the page where I have my form - without reloading the form page. When I try this code it refreshes the page and doesn't fetch the results.

The current jquery code where I have my form - form.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script>
$('#skipreload').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('GET'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('dbresults.php'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#form_output').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="skipreload" method="GET" action="form.php">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="Get results">
</form>

<div id="form_output">
<!--Show the result here from dbresults.php-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code in the page I want to fetch results from - dbresults.php:

```
include("dbsettings.php");

$id = "";

if ($_GET)
{
$id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT Results FROM Table WHERE id = '$id';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row["Results"]";
    }
}
```

When I'm submitting the form in form.php the page reloads without getting the result into the div "#form_output" from getresults.php - why doesn't it work?

Comment: Looking at your browser's developer console may have helped you solve this on your own. Just something to think about in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not attribute `GET` , that is a value for the `method` and there is no attribute `'dbresults.php'` that is a value for the `action` attribute.

In addition your code is being called before form exists

Try:

```
$(function(){ // wait until documented is ready so element exists

    $('#skipreload').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#form_output').html(response); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });

});
```

Comment: This code doesn't work though... It's using `form.php` instead of `dbresults.php`

Comment: I skipped the .attr(), but also enclosed it with the $(function() {... to wait until the document was ready, and then it solved it! :)

Comment: Great! I'm just saying credit is due for where you found that answer. Unless of course you found this answer "more helpful." Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call. Only use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) if you want to use the values currently on the form, and even then you need to select by the attribute **name** instead of the attribute **value**.

Change it to:

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: 'GET', // GET or POST
    url: 'dbresults.php', // the file to call
    success: function(response) { // on success..
        $('#form_output').html(response); // update the DIV
    }
});
```

You can also accomplish the same task by using [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get('dbresults.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    $('#form_output').html(response);
});
```

In addition, you need to wrap your code in a [`.ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // alternatively $(function() {
    [...]
});
```

Comment: I noticed that you aren't using a `ready` function to make sure that your code doesn't execute before the page has finished loading. Edited my answer.